# Obtaining the value of a variable set in executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope, return

While creating a Google Chrome extension, I have code that must remain in a separate javascript file:

```
separate.js
-----------
var x = "some dynamic value";
var y = "another dynamic value";
return x;
```

I would like to get the value of x from this code into a code included in my background page:

```
background.html
-----------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><script src="code.js"></script></head>
</html>
```

_

```
code.js
-----------
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"separate.js"}, function() {});
```

How do I go about retrieving a variable set in separate.js (say, y)? Is there a way to use executeScript() to get the return value of a script?

Comment: Use the [`chrome.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest) (at `separate.js`) and `chrome.onRequest` (at code.js).

Comment: I am unsure how to implement this. Could you show an example using the above context?

Comment: I have posted a very basic, trivial example which demonstrates how to use these methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your `code.js` (injected by your extension), make use of [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest):

```
var y = "variable to send";
function f_callback(response) {
    alert(response);
}
chrome.extension.sendRequest({y: y}, f_callback); //<-- Trigger
```

At `separate.js` (at `background.html`), use [`chrome.extension.onRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest):

```
function listener(o_request, o_sender, f_callback) {
    // This function is triggered by the function, see above
    alert(o_request.y); //<---y
    f_callback("Done something"); //<-- Calls callback. Can only be done once!
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(listener);
```

Comment: I see how the sendRequest and listener functions work and where they should reside but I do not see how the above causes code.js to send the request to separate.js. Where is the reference to separate.js?

Comment: `separate.js` is a part of `background.html`, the background page of your extension. When `...sendRequest(..)` is used at `code.js`, the background receives a request. This request can be captured by defining a listener (last line of my example).